# multi-dimensional list? List of lists? array of lists?

Tags: arrays, r, list, matrix, nested-lists

(I am definitively using wrong terminology in this question, sorry for that - I just don't know the correct way to describe this in R terms...)

I want to create a structure of heterogeneous objects. The dimensions are not necessary rectangular. What I need would be probably called just "array of objects" in other languages like C. By 'object' I mean a structure consisting of different members, i.e. just a list in R - for example:

```
myObject <- list(title="Uninitialized title", xValues=rep(NA,50), yValues=rep(NA,50))
```

and now I would like to make 100 such objects, and to be able to address their members by something like

```
for (i in 1:100) {myObject[i]["xValues"]<-rnorm(50)}
```

or

```
for (i in 1:100) {myObject[i]$xValues<-rnorm(50)}
```

I would be grateful for any hint about where this thing is described.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if all 100 objects are of the same type, then you can use a `matrix`. You can hold many different matrices in a single `list`.  ie, you will  have a `list of matrices`.   If the objects are of varying type, you can store them in a `data.frame` or a `list`, in which case you would have a `list of data.frames` or a `list of lists`.

Comment: If the dimensions are always going to be rectangular (in your case, 100x50), and the contents are always going to be homogeneous (in your case, numeric) then create an **array/matrix**. If you want the ability to add/delete/insert on individual lists (or change the data type), then use a **list-of-lists**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did not realize that you were looking for creating other objects of same structure. You are looking for `replicate`.

```
my_fun <- function() {
    list(x=rnorm(1), y=rnorm(1), z="bla")
}
replicate(2, my_fun(), simplify=FALSE)

# [[1]]
# [[1]]$x
# [1] 0.3561663
# 
# [[1]]$y
# [1] 0.4795171
# 
# [[1]]$z
# [1] "bla"
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$x
# [1] 0.3385942
# 
# [[2]]$y
# [1] -2.465932
# 
# [[2]]$z
# [1] "bla"
```

Comment: cool, that's another very good solution (in addition to example with lapply mentioned by thelatemail). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @VasilyA - Yep, `replicate` is just a wrapper around `sapply`, which is a cousin of `lapply`. The more you know ;-)

Comment: @thelatemail, is it possible to use it with ```mapply```? having really hard time to create lists of outputs from ```mapply```

Comment: @lodykvovchak - I think you may want Map instead of mapply. mapply will potentially simplify list outputs to a matrix or vector instead by default. (Map is just a wrapper for mapply with SIMPLIFY=FALSE set)

Answer (score 13):

are you looking for the name of this mythical beast or just how to do it?  :)  i could be wrong, but i think you'd just call it a list of lists..  for example:

```
# create one list object
x <- list( a = 1:3 , b = c( T , F ) , d = mtcars )

# create a second list object
y <- list( a = c( 'hi', 'hello' ) , b = c( T , F ) , d = matrix( 1:4 , 2 , 2 ) )

# store both in a third object
z <- list( x , y )

# access x
z[[ 1 ]] 

# access y
z[[ 2 ]]

# access x's 2nd object
z[[ 1 ]][[ 2 ]]
```

Comment: I was looking for the name simply to be able to make the right search query - to find some place where it is described and not to waste people's time for explaining this to me :)

Comment: in your example, you make an object containing 2 other objects of different types. What I need is to have 100 objects of the same composite structure (I don't know if it sounds more clear...).

Comment: @VasilyA, I think you have 100 lists (`A1, A2, ..., A100`). Now, make another list by doing `B <- list(A1, A2... A100`) (yes you have to type them). Then you can access `B[[1]][[2]]` for 2nd element of first list as Anthony has shown. If this isn't what you're looking for, then you'll have to edit your post to explain better. Because this is what it seems you're asking for.

Comment: yes, my case can be described as 100 lists - but of course typing them is not a solution for me (I put 100 as an example, it could be 1000) :[
After reading other similar questions, it seems for me that R cannot implement such thing, what a pity... Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @VasilyA - R certainly can implement such a thing - see my above comment.

Answer (score 2):

here is the example of solution I have for the moment, maybe it will be useful for somebody:

```
    NUM <- 1000 # NUM is how many objects I want to have
    xVal <- vector(NUM, mode="list")
    yVal <- vector(NUM, mode="list")
    title   <- vector(NUM, mode="list")
    for (i in 1:NUM) {
     xVal[i]<-list(rnorm(50))
     yVal[i]<-list(rnorm(50))
     title[i]<-list(paste0("This is title for instance #", i))
    }
   myObject <- list(xValues=xVal, yValues=yVal, titles=title)
   # now I can address any member, as needed:
   print(myObject$titles[[3]])
   print(myObject$xValues[[4]])
```

Comment: You might be able to do something simpler like: `lapply(1:10,function(y) list(title=paste("the title #",y,sep=""),x=rnorm(50),y=rnorm(50)) )` where `1:10` is the `1:n` number of lists that you want created.

Answer (score 1):

If the dimensions are always going to be rectangular (in your case, 100x50), and the contents are always going to be homogeneous (in your case, numeric) then create a 2D **array/matrix**.

If you want the ability to add/delete/insert on individual lists (or change the data type), then use a **list-of-lists**.

Comment: nope, I meant heterogeneous, not-necessary-rectangular objects. Sorry for not making it clear in my example

Comment: @VasilyA: ok, so click the 'edit' button on your question to say so. Not buried down here in comments which hardly anyone will read.